# Downloading the souce of a reddit thread to save locally. The HTML is the same but the page display is all messed up

Tags: html, css, reddit

I'm downloading one page from reddit and saving it locally:

http://www.reddit.com/r/TheRedPill/comments/2uomrv/meta_sjws_are_reportedly_working_with_admins_to/

The HTML is identical in my test.html file, but when I open the local file in a browser, the page display is all messed up. Right Nav disappears, etc.

Normally I'd assume this is a CSS issue (and it definitely could be) but there are only three CSS files in the document, and they are all hosted remotely on www.redditstatic.com -- so they should still be working, right?

Is there something else I'm missing?  Is redditstatic somehow smart enough to not serve CSS when I request it from my local machine?

What else could be causing the display issues?  How should I troubleshoot?

Comment: Try to copy this CSS files and load it from your local direction. We'll see is it problem with downloading CSS or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reddit uses external CSS, JavaScript, etc. to make it look as feel as it is. The website won't function correctly unless you download them all, even locally because **the HTML doesn't know where to find the called file.**